# Any way for site owners to "tag" sites to improve or augment search?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-search

Management would like site owners to have the ability to "tag" or provide keywords about their sites, to improve the findability of those sites in SharePoint Search (using on-prem SharePoint 2013 Enterprise).

I'm thinking of something similar the old meta HTML tag, where you could provide a description and keywords, and the old search engines would use those.

For example, if there is a site called "Financial Statements", an owner might tag it with the keywords "Balance Sheet" and "Income Statement", so a user searching for one of those two terms would see the "Financial Statements" site in the results. Sort of like Promoted Results, but I can't have those site owners going into Search Admin to do this or have them requesting IT do it every time they want to add a keyword.

Comment: Do you already have your taxonomy started?  You can allow members to add keywords if you choose.  This would build the database up for particular data sets, libraries, files, and lists.

Comment: This is a good question. I find that in the search results a document or list usually "over ranks" sites because of the amount of information they contain compared to the site description. I would suggest writing good site descriptions and then also creating a "sites" vertical for your Everything search. Hope somebody else comes up with some good stuff.

Comment: Found this tutorial on how to make a portal page for sites https://en.share-gate.com/blog/sharepoint-2013-content-search-site-portal it could be modified to work with the search results part and create a proper search experience for sites.